# Using expect in Perl with system()

Tags: linux, perl, bash, centos, expect

I am trying to use `expect` using system calls in a Perl script to recursively create directories on a remote server. The relevant call is as follows:

```
system("expect -c 'spawn  ssh  $username\@$ip; expect '*?assword:*' {send \"$password\r\"}; expect '*?*' {send \"mkdir -p ~/$remote_start_folder/$remote_folder_name/$remote_username/$remote_date/\r\"}; expect '*?*' {send \"exit\r\"};  interact;'");
```

This works fine. However, if it is the first time that the remote amchine is accessed using `ssh`, it asks for a `(yes/no)` confirmation. I don't know where to add that in the above statement. Is there a way to incorporate it into the above statement(using some sort of `or`-ing)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `yes/no` match to the same invocation of `expect` as the password match:

```
expect '*yes/no*' {send "yes\r"; exp_continue;} '*?assword:*' {send \"$password\r\"};
```

This will look for both matches, if `yes/no` is encountered `exp_continue` tells expect to keep looking for the password prompt.

Full example:

```
system( qq{expect -c 'spawn  ssh  $username\@$ip; expect '*yes/no*' {send "yes\r"; exp_continue;} '*?assword:*' {send "$password\r"}; expect '*?*' {send "mkdir -p ~/$remote_start_folder/$remote_folder_name/$remote_username/$remote_date/\r"}; expect '*?*' {send "exit\r"};  interact;'} );
```

I've also used [`qq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) to avoid having to escape all the quotation. Running this command from a shell with `-d` flag shows expect looking for either match:

```
Password: 
expect: does "...\r\n\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
    "*yes/no*"? no
    "*?assword:*"? yes
```

With `yes/no` prompt:

```
expect: does "...continue connecting (yes/no)? " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
    "*yes/no*"? yes
...
send: sending "yes\r" to { exp4 }
expect: continuing expect
...
expect: does "...\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
    "*yes/no*"? no
    "*?assword:*"? yes
...
send: sending "password\r" to { exp4 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating your life unnecessarily.

If you want expect-like functionality from Perl, just use the [Expect](https://metacpan.org/module/Expect) module.

If you want to interact with some remote server via SSH, use some of the SSH modules available from CPAN: [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2), [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny).

Pass the option `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to `ssh` if you don't want to confirm the remote host key.

For instance:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($ip, user => $username, password => $password,
                            master_opts => [-o => 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no']);

my $path = "~/$remote_start_folder/$remote_folder_name/$remote_username/$remote_date";
$ssh->system('mkdir -p $path')
    or die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;
```